# Move data from discs to hard drive with robotic changer device?

Tags: dvd, file-transfer, disc

How can I?  What can I buy?  Is it made?

A robotic disc-changer that allow a stack of already burnt discs to be read, taking simple PC data from the discs and off'ing it to the hard drive.

Would like to copy discs, 25 at a time, to a local hard drive.  Already have a Primera Bravo but no way to make it do that.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a [Ripstation](http://www.mfdigital.com/ripstation.html).

> Our 7601XDP is a low volume, single drive USB machine for small projects and needs a PC.If you are ripping less than 250 discs per week, 7601XDP will automated your workflow.

Rips CDs, DVDs, Audio, Video, Data.  Insert Stack, walk away.

**EDIT:**

Here's a different link to the same product: http://www.mfdigital.com/data_ripping.html

The text is more specific to what you are asking for. Otherwise, it's the same thing.